# What's the best webserver software for video?

Tags: video, webserver

we have a collection of FLV files, to be displayed by FlowPlayer flash-app in a website.
The scripts and handling of data are done with Apache/MySQL/PHP.
As the video files are static files they should be served by a more static oriented webserver like lighttpd or nginx, like it's done with photos.

What's the best webserver for serving video? A static files oriented webserver should be good?

thanks in advance
regards, rui

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this](http://superjared.com/entry/benching-lighttpd-vs-nginx-static-files/) benchmark, nginx is a little bit better than lighttpd for serving bigger static contents, so **nginx** would be a good choice for static flv video contents.

Comment: Everything I've read about nginx says use it for static content. However, for enough video serving you'll really need a CDN.

Answer (score 1):

[lighttpd](http://www.lighttpd.net/) - [YouTube uses it](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/wiki/lighttpd/poweredbylighttpd), as does ImageShack.

Comment: If I am not wrong, ImageShack no longer uses Lighttpd. Looks like they switched to Nginx.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at FF Server? [HERE IS THE LINK](http://ffmpeg.org/ffserver-doc.html)

We used it several time for our video serving needs and it has a nice interface. Several high volume video generating sites use this.